# Graph Transitivity Java

Tags: java, data-structures, graph

I'm using a custom graph to represent a set of data, as shown in the figure:

[image]

I have already created several methods that allow me to fill the structure. The main objective of this type of representation is to know quickly if a specific path exists. I have the following problem with the path search method:

For example, if I consider the paths "A-> D-> X", "B-> D -> #", "A-> E -> #", "A-> D -> #", then I would like to obtain the existence of the paths.
However, if I consider the path "B -> D -> X", I would like to get that the path does not exist.

Do you have any suggestions for developing this type of method without considering the initial data set?

Comment: If there is an edge d->x and an edge b->d, why doesn't the path b-d-x exist? Is this some kind of a special definition of the term "path"?

Comment: This is the problem: if b -> d and d -> b exist, there is no guarantee that b -> d -> x also exists (see input data). For this reason I ask you some suggestions for this representation

Comment: Generally, the transitive property holds in graph theory, but not in my case. However, there exist different theories in social graphs (see https://www.sci.unich.it/~francesc/teaching/network/transitivity.html) in which the Transitivity has been defined. But the theories are based on a probabilistic approach, and not deterministic.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you don't want B -> D -> X to be a valid path because you don't have an entry that says B|D|X. To know if a 'path' is valid it must exist in your table as-is. I'm not sure a graph is the proper structure then. An array of tuples would do the trick.

Comment: So the only valid paths are what you have in your table?

Comment: @Joni Yes, only valid paths are defined in the table.

Comment: @ArthurAttout I don't want to use a list of tuples because the number of columns and rows in the table can increase significantly.
If I use a table, I have a lot of data redundancy, so the complexity for the search increases.

Answer (score 2):

If the only available paths are the ones in your table, you can use any implementation of a set data structure, like `HashSet` or `TreeSet` in Java. Just add all the paths to the set, and then use the `Set.contains` method to check if a path is valid.

This will work reasonably well as long as the valid paths are short or there is a small number of them. If there is a large number of paths, and they are long, you'll get better performance with other data structures.

For example a [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) is a collection for sequences of items, that lets you check if a sequence is present in time proportional to the length of the sequence. It has been traditionally used for strings, but you can easily use it for graph paths. In this usage, the nodes in the trie would store nodes of your graph, so that a path in the trie corresponds to a valid path in your graph.

Comment: Trie is a good choice if I had a sequence of char. I have shown this example to simplify the explanation of the problem. However, I can also have the string as a node element.

Comment: Put your *graph nodes* in the trie. It's not limited to single characters or strings, it's a general data structure for sequences of any type of data you might have. In your case, the sequences are paths in your graph.

Comment: I will try to create a custom Trie. Thanks for your suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Making two assumptions here:

1. The edges are bidirectional;
2. Unlike the examples you have listed, you are not looking for 3-node (or 2-edge) paths only, meaning `A->E->#->D->B` is also a valid path and should return true.

---

The [Disjoint Sets / Union-Find Data Structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint_sets) gives you just that ability.

In this DS, which has more than one underlying implementations, all connected nodes will be in the same set. Thus If you have *n* connected components, then you will have as many disjoint-sets.

To find if there is a path between node-1 and node-2, just see if they are in the same set.

Comment: I want to consider any valid paths consisting of a maximum of 3-nodes. Thus, I'm not interested to search A->E->#->D->B. I'm sorry I didn't specify that.

Comment: Will leave the answer here in case someone stumbles upon this question, but not having the three nodes constraints like you. :)